# PowerShell - Need to test if item contained in a list

Tags: powershell

I have an object that holds a list of patches (actually 2 lists)
One of the patches in the list contains the words "Cumulative Update" in his title so I run in a loop and find the one that holds this string in the TFS.
In the next step I take the patch ($match, in my case is 1307131) and fetch all the relations URLs. from now on I don't know how to continue :). Each url holds at the end the number of the patch that contained in the CU path ($match).
The goal is to find if any patch in $patchesList is listed in the CU patch (1307131) and if it does need to print them (except the CU himself of course).
For an example if 1292054 and 1295392 are part of 1307131 so the result should be that 1292054 and 1295392 already contained in the CU patch.
This solution should be a part of a big script so if there is result (means that one of the patches in $patchesList is already listed under the CU) the script should stop

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SharePointSiteURL # -Credentials $PSCredentials 
    $ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($SharePointSiteURL)  
    $ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("VIP List")
    
    Write-host "Worksheet was opened"
    Write-host
    $rowMax = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count # get the number of rows in the sheet
    $colMax = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count # get the number of columns in the sheet

$patches = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
        $color = $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, [uint16]$columnID).Interior.ColorIndex # 2 is column B
        $value = $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, [uint16]$columnID).Value2
        if ($color -eq $searchcolorForPatch -and $value -eq $valueToSearchForPatches ) {
            # output an object with both values from columns A and B
            [PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2 }
        }
    }

# In real life this list of objects comes from an Excel sheet
$patchesList = @(ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Patch
1292054
1295392
1307131
1259868
1322467
1324214
1292054
1295392
1307131
1259868
1322467
1324214
'@)

foreach ($patches in $patchesList) {
    foreach ($patch in $patches) {

        $title = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patch.Patch).fields.'system.Title'
        if ($title -like "Cumulative Update") {
            $match = $patch.Patch
        }
    }

}
$match

$CU_title = Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $match -Expand All
$Urls = $CU_title.relations
foreach ($url in $Urls) {
    $url | Where-Object { $_.rel -eq 'System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse' } 
   
}
```

The result of this is:

```
rel                                 url                                                                   attributes                                                    
---                                 ---                                                                   ----------                                                    
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1292054 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1295392 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1295145 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1289076 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1297571 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1298737 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1293404 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1297096 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1296487 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1284666 @{isLocked=False; comment=Included in Patch; name=Predecessor}



CU          patch
1307131     1292054,1295392
        
Or 
        
CU          patch
1307131     1292054
1307131     1295392


Not

CU          patch
1307131     1292054
1307131     1295392
1307131     1307131
```

Comment: @Mathias Sorry don't understand your question

Comment: The numbers are the patches that $patchesList holds, $patchesList is collected from excel sheet.

Comment: You can take it as a constant. The patches are changing according the excel sheet. I collect them in every run.
I thought the question is clear

Comment: Gotcha, I re-wrote your example slightly to make it syntactically valid

Comment: Its not convert from CSV. I will add how the patches are collected. But its not relevant to my question...

Comment: I know it's not CSV _in real life_, but writing it this way allows other users to actually _execute and test your script_ without getting a syntax error :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change your double foreach loop into

```
$match = foreach ($patch in $patchesList) {
    $title = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patch.Patch).fields.'system.Title'
    if ($title -like '*Cumulative Update*') {  # use wildcards for -like
        # output the patch ID. It will collect in variable $match
        [int]$patch.Patch
    }
}
```

Seeing that [Get-VSTeamWorkItem](https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Get-VSTeamWorkItem/) can take an array of patch ids `[int32[]]`, you may even try this (untested)

```
$match = Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id ([int[]]$patchesList.Patch) -Expand All | 
         Where-Object { $_.fields.'system.Title' -like '*Cumulative Update*' }
foreach ($url in $match.relations) {
    $url | Where-Object { $_.rel -eq 'System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse' } 
}
```

---

I cannot test this myself, but you could try to match the PatchId's with their cumulative update ID's like below:

```
$match = Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id ([int[]]$patchesList.Patch) -Expand All | 
         Where-Object { $_.fields.'system.Title' -like '*Cumulative Update*' } | 
         ForEach-Object {
            $patch   = $_
            $relUrls = ($patch.relations | Where-Object { $_.rel -eq 'System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse' }).url
            # output objects
            foreach ($url in $relUrls) {
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    CU    = ($url -split '/')[-1]
                    Patch = $patch.Id
                }
            }
         }

# output on screen
$match

# output to CSV file
$match | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\Patches.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi @Theo 
The second part of $match= get-VS... is working and I can get all the urls that holds the patches but now what?
I got the same result as it was in the long way

Comment: @Bandit Please see my edit. I can't test this out myself, so if you get errors or weird results, please let me know if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: thank you very much I will test it as soon as I will be at home

Comment: Hi @Theo 
There are no errors but I got all the list of 'System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse'
One row that holds the CU patch and anther row that holds all the related patches of CU Instead of the common patches for for $patchesList and the CU

Comment: Theo 
Its make sense because PsCustomObject contains only the CU and all the related patches.
I don't see the the part that should compare with the $patchesList ...
As I wrote the goal is display only the common patches from $patchesList and related CU (Excluding the CU himself)

Comment: @Bandit the `Get-VSTeamWorkItem` is using the patches list as `-Id` parameter, so we're only asking for id's in that list...

Comment: Theo don’t understand your comment, How can I get my answer?  As I said the script returns all the patches under CU regardless the list of $patchesList